# How to mail to users if count generated in a text file is not equal to 0

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have a select query which runs and generate the count. It exports the Answer in a text file which has below records eg.:

```
Unprocessed record for A Sources
----------------------Unprocessed record count for ABC SOURCE ------------------
abc_count=            0
--------------------Unprocessed record count for CDE Source --------
CDE_count=            0
-----------------------Unprocessed record count for DEF Source -----------------
DEF_count=            0
------------------Unprocessed record count for GHI Source ----------------------
GHI_count=            56
```

I want to write a Unix command which checks if for above source any of the count is not equal to 0 then mail it to the required team.

This is what I used previously but is not working.

```
for CHECK in $(awk '{print $1}' hello | grep count=| cut -d"=" -f1) do
    if [ $(grep $CHECK output.txt | awk '{print $2}') -ne 0 ] then
        echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt)" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is what i used previously but is not working

for CHECK in $(awk '{print $1}' hello | grep count=| cut -d"=" -f1) 
do 
if [ $(grep $CHECK output.txt | awk '{print $2}') -ne 0 ] 
then 
echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt)" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com 
fi 
done

Comment: please help me with any thing new or let me know if above one has any sytactical error

Answer (score 0):

You should add a semicolon `;` in `if` statement before `then` and in `for` before `do`. If no more issues it should work. Also I'm not improving your script.

The script.

```
for CHECK in $(awk '{print $1}' hello | grep count=| cut -d"=" -f1); do
    if [ $(grep $CHECK output.txt | awk '{print $2}') -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$(grep $CHECK output.txt)" | mailx -s "CHECK ABC PROCESS" foo@bar.com
    fi
done
```

Also it's not you should have your `cut` command as this `cut -d"=" -f2` to get number value? also better run your commands out of loop to see if you got any result or not.

Answer (score 0):

To send an email to `foo@bar.com` if the file contains an assignment of anything non-zero to anything:

1. Filter out all lines with assignments.  This may be done with `grep '='` (alternatively `grep 'count=' if you need to be more specific).
2. Remove lines with lone zeroes.  This may be done with `grep -v -w '0'` (`-w` to match only complete words, i.e. not `10` in this case).
3. Act on the result.

```
if grep '=' output.txt | grep -q -v -w '0'; then
    grep '=' output.txt | grep -v -w '0' | mailx -s "Check this out!" foo@bar.com
fi
```

For the data in the question, that will send an email containing

```
GHI_count=            56
```

---

If it feels unnecessary to run *four* greps for this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
grep '=' output.txt | grep -v -w '0' >"$tmpfile"

if [ -s "$tmpfile" ]; then
    mailx -s "Check this out!" foo@bar.com <"$tmpfile"
fi

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

The `-s` test will be true if the file exists and has a size greater than zero.